Why was the animal "Wolf" used in the title "The Wolf of Wall Street (2013)"?
The most commonly known animals in Wall Street are the bull and the bear, which represent optimistic and pessimistic investors or traders, respectively.
The movie "The Wolf of Wall Street (2013)", discusses the pump and dump scheme run by Jordan Belfort.
Why was the animal "Wolf" used in the title "The Wolf of Wall Street (2013)"?

A wolf is a predatory animal.

Bull and bear refer to the state of the market as a whole, not to individuals.

The Koala of Wall Street just doesn't have the same ring.

lol. As I expected, it's a self-given nickname. He's not the first to use it, either. The expression goes back to the 1920s

a good start might be the dictionary definition of wolf - Google gives it as "used figuratively to refer to a rapacious, ferocious, or voracious person or thing."

It contrasts well with "sheep", a derogatory term for investors who blindly follow the trends and decisions of others. And alliteration is always helpful in a memorable phrase.

Downvoted for lack of research. The answer is given in the tag excerpt of [tag:the-wolf-of-wall-street].

@JörgWMittag - I think we can assume that OP means why in a broader sense, As in "who gave him the nickname and why?"

@DanielR.Collins They also refer to people who have particular attitudes: bulls are people that are predicting the stock market to go up, and bears are people that are predicting it to go down. E.g. Michael Burry was a bear in 2006.

The earliest use of the phrase "Wolf of Wall Street" I found to describe a real person was David Lamar who conducted a series of different criminal activities in New York from 1893 until his death in 1934. Here is the 1934 New York Times article describing Lamar's death which mentions the phrase. In this context it's very clear the intent of this phrase was purely disparaging, describing a deceptive criminal.
 
The 1929 movie cited in another answer here uses the phrase in a similar way, to describe a fictional character who is "ruthless" and ruins people's finances via his short selling scheme.
I also found a 1983 New York Times article by Nathaniel C. Nash that uses the phrase for a different person:

T. Boone Pickens Jr., dubbed the ''wolf'' of Wall Street by a Gulf spokesman…


This reference to how Pickens is a savvy, even a predatory investor who was a part of many takeovers and corporate raids. Unlike the Lamar usage there is no implication of criminality here.
(Note I've also searched on multiple sites including the New York Times, PressReader, Gale Academic OneFile for any reference to Tom Redburn and Belfort / "wolf of wall street" as mentioned in another answer here and I haven't found anything.)
So it's clear the phrase has been around for a long time, was used to describe multiple people, and was not coined by either Belfort or Redburn.
Wolves are very frequently used as villains and sly, devious characters in western folklore, such as in Little Red Riding Hood, The Three Little Pigs, and the concept of a wolf in sheep's clothing which comes from Jesus in the New Testament.

Jordan Belfort's devious and criminal financial shenanigans are thus similarly compared to a villainous wolf.
In addition to the fact as others have mentioned here that this was the title of the memoir by Belfort that the movie was based on, it's worth also noting that animals are commonly-used symbolism in the context of Wall Street. You've got bears and bulls, and you also have whales, sharks, sheep, and even unicorns, and there are many more. Michael Ewing Purves developed the concept of a "wolf market" as an alternative to a bull or bear market to describe a certain kind of volatile market.
However, wolves are also often seen as fierce and powerful and even majestic predators and as (misguided) symbols of masculinity, so it's not necessarily surprising that Belfort embraced this nickname as the title of his memoir. He is not trying to hide or justify his crimes, but he's also glorifying them, as implied by the subtitle of the book:

Stock Market Multimillionaire at 26, Federal Convict at 36, I Partied like a Rock Star, Lived like a King, and Barely Survived
My Rise and Fall as an American Entrepreneurial Icon


Also the word "wolf" pairs nicely with "wall" as an alliteration and both being one syllable and four letters (though I have yet to find a credible worm or a wasp of wall street).

Just a few weeks ago this event discussing the book "Billion Dollar Whale" was called "The Whale of Wall Street".

Belfort seems to have given himself the nickname to sell his sensationalist book, according to Jordan's long time friend and former business partner, Danny Porush, who says that he never once heard anyone use the expression.

Porush’s quibbles start with the book’s cover—and the film’s title:
Porush says he never heard anyone at the firm refer to Belfort as the
“wolf.” And while sex was nearly as integrated into office life as the
scams that made the firm’s owners millions, Porush strongly denies a
long-established piece of Stratton lore detailed in the book, and
dramatized in the film adaptation: that brokers became so debauched
that Belfort was forced to issue a memo declaring the office a
“fuck-free zone” from 8 a.m. to 7 p.m. on workdays.
Dwarf-Tossing, 3-Way With Teen Employee Never Happened, Says Real “Wolf of Wall Street” Exec

In the source novel Jordan claims "The Wolf of Wall Street" was a legitimate nickname...

I had lots of nicknames: Gordon Gekko, Don Corleone, Kaiser Soze; they
even called me the King. But my favorite was the Wolf of Wall Street,
because that was me to a T. I was the ultimate wolf in sheep’s
clothing: I looked like a kid and acted like a kid, but I was no kid.
I was thirty-one going on sixty, living dog years—aging seven years
for every year. But I was rich and powerful and had a gorgeous wife
and a four-month-old baby daughter who was living, breathing
perfection.
The Wolf of Wall Street by Jordan Belfort.

...but as with most serial fabulists who write their memoirs, Belfort can't help but give a little bit too much away. Evidently he saw it on TV and liked it.

There was a reason for that: While watching Gilligan’s Island reruns,
I made the shocking discovery that I was not the only Wolf of Wall
Street. Much to my chagrin, there was someone sharing this
not-so-honorable distinction with me, and he happened to be a bumbling
old WASP who’d been unlucky enough to get himself shipwrecked on
Gilligan’s Island. His name was Thurston Howell III, and, alas, he
truly was an idiot WASP. In typical WASP fashion he’d married a female
of his species, an atrocious pineapple blond named Lovey, who was
almost as great an idiot as he but not quite. Lovey felt it necessary
to wear wool pantsuits, sequined ball gowns, and a full face of
makeup, despite the fact that Gilligan’s Island was somewhere in the
South Pacific, at least five hundred miles from the nearest shipping
lane where she would ever be seen by anyone. But WASPs are notorious
overdressers.
I found myself wondering if it was only by sheer coincidence that the
original Wolf of Wall Street was a bumbling moron or if my nickname
was meant to be a slight—comparing Jordan Belfort to an old WASP
bastard with an IQ of sixty-five and a penchant for bed-wetting.
Perhaps, I thought glumly, perhaps.


For the record, the expression has been in regular usage since at least the 1920s, as evidenced by the 1929 film of the same name.


A ruthless stockbroker sells short in the copper business and ruins the life of his friends by ruining their finances.


A quick trip to Wikipedia reveals

The Wolf of Wall Street is a 2013 American biographical black comedy
film co-produced and directed by Martin Scorsese and written by
Terence Winter, based on Jordan Belfort's 2007 memoir of the same
name.

In the book / movie, Jordan Belfort is portrayed as a ruthless and cunning individual who used his skills to manipulate the stock market for personal gain. Choosing a wolf as a symbol may reflect Belfort's predatory nature, aggressive tactics and his ability to thrive in the competitive and cutthroat world of finance.

The name was coined by a journalist in an earlier interview iirc, jordan just adopted it

@blobbymcblobby where can I find that information, who was the interviewer?

@blobbymcblobby - I can't find any interview with that nickname that predates Belfort's book

The problem with Wikipedia is, of course, that anyone can write any nonsense and it immediately becomes fact.

The name “The Wolf of Wall Street” was not originally coined by Jordan Belfort, but particularly by a journalist who covered his life and activities on Wall Street. The journalist who phrases it was Tom Redburn of the New York Times.
Since the main characters (in real life and in the movie) have too many similarities, like wolves, this word is used.
Reference link: NY Times biz desk says goodbye to the “Watchdog of Wall Street”
It stated:

And then there’s this from Dean Murphy:  “Tom Redburn once said, there is the Wolf of Wall Street — and then there’s Gretchen, the Watchdog of Wall Street.


Do you have a source for this? Looked briefly on Google and The New York Times but haven't found it yet.

@shim - Me neither. I've found a couple of people attributing it to him, but never with a link to any articles.

@shim reference link added.

That reference is from 2017 and doesn't say that he coined it.

@Valorum  it stated that Redburn said that word: there is the Wolf of Wall Street which points out  Jordan Belfort because the journalist covered his life

@Death-is-the-real-truth - I see no evidence in that article that he's referring to Belfort or that he coined the phrase. The article is written a decade after Belfort's book came out, and the film

You say he popularised it, but I can't find a single article where he even used it

I saw that link too, but that is such an indirect reference that doesn’t really prove the claim. I’m not saying it isn’t true, just that if Redburn wrote an article even using the phrase it should be possible to find that article.

@shim - It also doesn't say whether Redburn is even referring to Belfort

Oh yea good point. Just says he said the phrase.

I remember that in the tv series The Beverly Hillbillies (1962-1971) the Clampett's  banker Milburn Drysdale would do anything to keep Jed's millions invested in his bank.  Mr. Drysdale sometimes called himself "The Wolf of Wall Street", believing he was a ruthless and brilliant investor.
And either the writers remembered David Lamar's nickname "The Wolf of Wall Street" mentioned in Shim's answer, or made it up themselves by similar thought processes.  And it is quite possible that earlier shady dealers had been called "the Wolf of Wall Street".
Hetty Green (1834-1916) was a briliant investor and famous miser, called "The Queen of Wall Street" and "The Witch of Wall Street".
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hetty_Green

I didn't find a reference to "wolf of wall street" in The Beverly Hillbillies; just a reference to a "fox of wall street". S02E28 The Great Crawdad Hunt, it's around the 4:40 mark here (dailymotion link, couldn't find it anywhere else)
